# Keyboard hooks without using a DLL?

Tags: keyboard, hook, global

I'm trying to create a program with some key bindings (F1-F12) which will pick up the key presses while out of focus (specifically, while a game is running).

Is there anyway to detect these key presses without using a global hook?  The language I am programming in (real studio) doesn't have a means of creating a DLL (required for a global hooks), plus, I'm hoping of having it cross platform with mac (which is what realstudio does).

Comment: What programming language are you using? I could update my answer with some sample code if that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While as klartex says, a low-level keyboard/mouse hook does not require a DLL (unlike all other types of hooks), a hook of *any* kind is certainly overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

**All you need is the [`RegisterHotKey` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx)**, which allows you to register any key (or combination of keys) as a system-wide hotkey. This fulfills your requirement of being able to pick up the key presses even while your application is out of focus.

As a bonus, `RegisterHotKey` does not require a DLL nor is it as "heavy" as a system-wide hook. Hooks have a negative effect on performance; you shouldn't see that with `RegisterHotKey`.

Once you've registered a hot key by calling the function, you handle [`WM_HOTKEY` messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646279.aspx) inside of your application's window procedure. Once you're finished, make sure that you call the [`UnregisterHotKey` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327.aspx) to unregister your application as handling that hot key.

The only caveat here is mentioned in the documentation:

> The F12 key is reserved for use by the debugger at all times, so it should not be registered as a hot key. Even when you are not debugging an application, F12 is reserved in case a kernel-mode debugger or a just-in-time debugger is resident.

But the same issue would apply if you were installing a low-level keyboard hook. <kbd>F12</kbd> is just not a good candidate hot key, regardless of the application. If you absolutely must, use it at your own risk.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! :)

Fortunately I don't require F12 but thanks for the heads up on that.  

Very much appreciated.  As with all the other replys too.

Comment: I know this was an old topic but have now got around to "finishing" the application.

I've managed to use register hot key, but it does not work during the game i intended it to be used during?  Is there any reason why it would not be working through the game?

Answer (score 0):

With this you should be able to hook keyboard without DLL on windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[`RegisterHotKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not require a dll.