# VBNET Create HotKey shared only for the entire Application

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

Basically i am creating a vbnet system software. I want to create a shortcut key to lock the system with out affecting the windows explorer (*just my system only*). Is it possible to create one for that? Or let's say create a procedure that triggers anywhere whether the focus is on a control, on a form (*whether shown as normal or modal*), or on any other that has the focus on it.

I just need an idea. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keyboard hooks without using a DLL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562006/keyboard-hooks-without-using-a-dll) Another easier option would be a menu item with a shortcut key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use hotkey registration to do it.

Here is one of a few existing walk throughs on accessing user32.dll to [register a global hotkey](http://www.kirsbo.com/2010/how-to-add-global-hotkeys-to-applications-in-vb-net/)

I think the key for you will be where to register the hotkey and make sure to unregister it when your application closes.